# Setup for a CLI python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface

I have a CLI python program and i am planning to release it. How would i make it so that the user who installs it can run it from anywhere as a command. It has some additional dependencies so a virtual environment will be used by many as well, which might be a problem while running the program from anywhere

I saw answers saying to put it in `usr/bin/` and then add to path, but it would still require the virtual environment to be active. Also it would be helpful if there was any cross-platform way.